# Unzipping .7z File on Google Colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, unzip, 7zip

I have a Zip file named 'mathoverflow.net.7z' in my google drive which I have loaded to colab using the given code. But, when I try to unzip it I get an error. Please suggest a way to rectify this.

This is my code:

```
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':'15h0f8p9n6OG1B796q-gbP5oXstCuOcDM'})
downloaded.GetContentFile('mathoverflow.net.7z')
```

Till this it works fine. But when I run this I get the following error.

```
!unzip mathoverflow.net.7z
```

> Archive:  mathoverflow.net.7z   End-of-central-directory signature not
> found.  Either this file is not   a zipfile, or it constitutes one
> disk of a multi-part archive.  In the   latter case the central
> directory and zipfile comment will be found on   the last disk(s) of
> this archive. unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of
> mathoverflow.net.7z or
> mathoverflow.net.7z.zip, and cannot find mathoverflow.net.7z.ZIP, period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `7z` instead. It's already pre-installed in Colab

```
!7z e mathoverflow.net.7z
```

Comment: This worked but I can see the unzipped files only on colab, should I let it be that way or is there a way (or need) to have these unzipped files on google drive?

Comment: You can mount drive and move the files back. Search for the question how. It's easier than pydrive.

Comment: Okay, Thank You.

Comment: I am getting the following error while unzipping a 7z file using this code `ERROR: /content/drive/My Drive/SO Full Data/7z Files/Posts.7z
Can not open the file as archive

Unknown error -2147024891`. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
!pip install pyunpack
!pip install patool

from pyunpack import Archive
Archive('file_name.7z').extractall('path/to/')
```

Answer (score 0):

unzip will not work, you need a different tool: https://www.simplified.guide/linux/extract-7z-file

I don't know that you have installation privileges on colab, so you might have to do it in the privacy of your own machine.